# Iterator wrapper to interogate instances before returning to caller

Tags: rust, iterator

tl;dr in Rust, I want a struct to provide an Iterator on a contained iterable struct member but to interrogate the iterated values before returning them

### General Overview

1. A "wrapper" struct contains a "specialized container".
2. the "wrapper" should implement an Iterator function `next`
3. within `next` the "wrapper" will call the "specialized container" `next`,
4. the "wrapper" will analyze the value returned from the "specialized container"
5. the "wrapper" will return the value to the caller

### Specific Example

My specific case deals with rust crate [`evtx`](https://docs.rs/evtx/latest/evtx/). I would like to do the following:

1. my "wrapper" struct, `RecordsReader`, contains an [`EvtxParser`](https://docs.rs/evtx/latest/evtx/struct.EvtxParser.html).
2. the `RecordsReader` implements Iterator function `into_iter` and `next` which returns a `std::result::Result<SerializedEvtxRecord<String>, EvtxError>`
3. within function `RecordsReader::next`
   a. it calls [`self.evtxparser.records()`](https://docs.rs/evtx/latest/evtx/struct.EvtxParser.html#method.records), creates an iterator
   b. the result of `self.evtxparser.records().next()` is a `SerializedEvtxRecord<String>`. That instance is analyzed and various statistics about it stored within `RecordsReader` instance.
   c. the `SerializedEvtxRecord<String>` instance is then returned to the caller of `recordsreader.next()`.
   d. ***the state of the iterator created by `self.evtxparser.records()` is maintained between calls to `recordsreader.next()`.*** *(how to do this part?)*

Partial rust code ([rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1818e3dda4b58b84c694a08bf156190f) (will not compile because evtx crate is not available)):

```rust
use ::evtx::{
    err::EvtxError,
    EvtxParser,
    SerializedEvtxRecord,
};
use std::fs::File;
use std::path::PathBuf;

pub type EvtxRS = SerializedEvtxRecord<String>;
pub type ResultEvtxRS = std::result::Result<EvtxRS, EvtxError>;
pub type EParser = EvtxParser<File>;


struct RecordsReader {
    pub eparser: EParser,
}
pub struct RecordsReaderIterator<'a> {
    recordsreader: &'a mut RecordsReader,
    index: usize, // hack iterator state
}
impl<'a> Iterator for RecordsReaderIterator<'a> {
    type Item = ResultEvtxRS;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<ResultEvtxRS> {
        // ----------------------------------------------
        // HOW TO AVOID RECREATING THE self.recordsreader.parser.records()
        // ON EVERY CALL OF next() ?
        // Or, at least, make next() into *O(n)* time?
        // ----------------------------------------------
        // Hack iterator approach; O(n^2)
        let result = 
            self.recordsreader.eparser.records().nth(self.index);
        self.index += 1;
        // ... store other statistics about `result` before returning it ...
        result
    }
}
impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a mut RecordsReader {
    type Item = ResultEvtxRS;
    type IntoIter = RecordsReaderIterator<'a>;
    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        RecordsReaderIterator {
            recordsreader: self,
            index: 0,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let pathb = PathBuf::from("file.evtx");
    let mut eparser: EParser = EParser::from_path(pathb).unwrap();
    let mut recordsreader: RecordsReader = RecordsReader {
        eparser,
    };
    for recordopt in recordsreader.into_iter() {
        match recordopt {
            ResultEvtxRS::Ok(record) => {
                eprintln!("record[{:?}] {:?}", record.event_record_id, record.timestamp);
            }
            ResultEvtxRS::Err(err) => {
                eprintln!("ERROR: {}", err);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The prior code functions *BUT* `next()` is *O(n^2)* time!
That's because the state of the `self.recordsreader.eparser.records()` iterator cannot be saved. That "inner iterator" must be recreated on every call to `next()`.

***How can I implement an Iterator function for `RecordsReader` that does not have to reset the "inner iterator" state of `eparser.records()` on every call?***
Barring that question, how can `next()` become *O(n)* time?

---

##### Similar Questions

I read the Answers to these Questions. As far as I could determine, these are similar *but not quite the same* as this Question. (I tried to implement many of these Answers but was unable)

- [What is the correct way to return an Iterator (or any other trait)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535289/what-is-the-correct-way-to-return-an-iterator-or-any-other-trait)
- [What return type should I use for an iterable expression? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46509583/what-return-type-should-i-use-for-an-iterable-expression)
- [How do you create an iterator using a closure in rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26860905/how-do-you-create-an-iterator-using-a-closure-in-rust)
- [How to return chained iterators in rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61853531/how-to-return-chained-iterators-in-rust)
- [How to return a boxed clonable iterator in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49594732/how-to-return-a-boxed-clonable-iterator-in-rust)

Comment: Should you not just store the result of calling `recordsreader.eparser.records()` in the iterator? Why are you recreating the iterator every invocation? `RecordsReaderIterator::recordsreader` should just be an iterator, then you delegate to its `next()`.  This is exactly what `.map()` does... which you could probably use here instead of this construction.

Comment: note: `next()` already is O(n), you want calling `next()` n times to be O(n) which happens if `next()` is O(1)

Comment: @cdhowie "_Should you not just store the result of calling recordsreader.eparser.records() in the iterator?_" I played around with trying to do this; many permutations of this code. I couldn't figure out how to store the iterator instance. Every permutation refused to compile.  I could have included all those failed attempts in my Question but it was too much to explain.
"_Why are you recreating the iterator every invocation?_" That's what I'm trying to avoid doing, hence the Question.
"_what .map() does..._" I'll try using `map`. Thanks!

Comment: @cafce25 "_next() already is O(n), you want calling next() n times to be O(n) which happens if next() is O(1)_". Yes, to clarify, I couldn't figure out how to only call `next` for _O(n)_ times. The example I provided is known to be a bad implementation. My Question is, how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest is to just use [`Iterator::inspect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.inspect):

```
use ::evtx::{
    err::EvtxError,
    EvtxParser,
    SerializedEvtxRecord,
};
use std::fs::File;
use std::path::PathBuf;

pub type EvtxRS = SerializedEvtxRecord<String>;
pub type ResultEvtxRS = std::result::Result<EvtxRS, EvtxError>;
pub type EParser = EvtxParser<File>;

fn main() {
    let pathb = PathBuf::from("file.evtx");
    let mut eparser: EParser = EParser::from_path(pathb).unwrap();
    for recordopt in eparser.into_iter()
            .inspect (|record| todo!("Add record to statistics") {
        match recordopt {
            ResultEvtxRS::Ok(record) => {
                eprintln!("record[{:?}] {:?}", record.event_record_id, record.timestamp);
            }
            ResultEvtxRS::Err(err) => {
                eprintln!("ERROR: {}", err);
            }
        }
    }
}
```